# O que é uma metaclasse em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

O que é uma metaclasse em Python? Em que ocasiões deve-se usá-las?

Comment: sugestão de leitura(em inglês) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/5165064